# way to attach context to a variable but not influence its effective value

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, data-structures

I want to be able to attach context to a string but not be part of the string value itself.

Example:

```
x = "leak"(gearbox)
y = "leak"(seal)
```

I want store this in a way where I can still be able to count how many times "leak" occurs but still have the context of each stay attached to it. In this case "leak" occurs twice.

I need to be able to store these values in a pandas DataFrame so a dictionary wouldn't work.

Comment: Could you please explain your requirement properly

Comment: Why not store them in different columns of the df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass [`collections.UserString`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserString) to hold custom attributes:

```py
from collections import UserString

class MyString(UserString):
    def __init__(self, val, /, context=None):
        super().__init__(val)
        self.context = context
```